# Odoo : How could I make my customer becoming users?

Tags: database, web, crm, odoo

I'm into a BtoC company and I'm using Odoo. I'd love to have the possibility to make my customer (so in the CRM) becoming a user and then they could have the possibility to log in in my website. Like this, I could keep all the information about the customer when he is becoming a user ! Do you think it's possible ? Do you know any module which does that ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

Hello Alexandre Maurin,

In ODOO (formally OpenERP) Use the different Object while creating the

customer as well as the user

For Customer (partner) Use As **res.partner** object while creating the New Record in Customer(Partner)

And the  For the User use As the **res.users** object while creating the New Record in Users

**One Of the Simple steps you have to Follow :**

1.create the new python file and inherit the **res.partner** object in your file.

2.override the create of orm in your inherited **res.partner** object file.

3.And create the new record in  the in orm create method of **res.partner** file for **res.user** using create method of res.user and then the new user will automatically created while you are creating the customer(partner).

I hope this should help for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It sounds easy, I wasn't thinking about that, but I'm pretty sure it could work !

Comment: This could never work: res.users inherits res.partner, thus calling res.users.create from inside res.partner.create will result in a infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

You can use view inheritance.

Inherit *base.view_users_form*. Change partner_id to visible and make *name* and *image* readonly:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_customer_users_form">
    <field name="name">customer.users.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="partner_id" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': False}</attribute>
            <attribute name="readonly">False</attribute>
            <attribute name="required">True</attribute>
            <attribute name="domain">[('customer','=',True),('is_company','=',False)]</attribute>
        </field>
        <field name="name" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </field>
        <label for="login" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="string">Login name</attribute>
        </label>
        <field name="image" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </field>                 
    </field>
</record>
```

Add window action and menu item:

```
<record id="action_customer_users_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Add customer user </field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.users</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_customer_users_form"/>
</record>        
<record id="action_customer_users_view2" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_customer_users_form"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_customer_users_form"/>
</record>
<menuitem action="action_customer_users_form" id="user_customer_form" parent="base.menu_users" sequence="2"/>
```